# Fbric.js - Clip image to bounding box in version 4.5.0

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm building an application with fabric.js an we need to restrict an area on canvas where overlay images can be added. Like https://jsfiddle.net/PromInc/ZxYCP/. This script is written using the version **1.7** using the `clipTo` property and this property is deprecated in version **4.5.0** and replaced with `clipPath` but it is not working like `clipTo`.

This is what I'm trying to do using `clipPath` https://jsfiddle.net/hassanrazadev/kcdp39nw/11/ but is making the image transparent and not clipping it when going outside the print area.

How can I achieve what I want? Am I on right track?

The similar question asked here but not yet answered / answer not clear

- [fabric.js: how to create bounding box for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57480615/8325024)
- [fabric js code not working with newest version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67810180/8325024)

I tried using `clipPath` property to clip the image and I'm expecting that the image should be clipped when moving outside the print area